# How do I add a specific time-server?

Tags: time, ntp

At work I can only connect to a specific ntp time-server. Under Ubuntu 10.10 I was able to add that server somewhere under time/date settings. Now under Ubuntu 11.04 I cannot find that option anymore.

I am sure that there is a config somewhere that I can edit to add the approved server.

Can you please give me some pointers?

Edit: I should probably mention that I use the classic desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to do some manual editing using nano, or your editor of choice:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/ntpdate
```

and change the `NTPSERVERS="ntp.[your-server-here]"`

If you restart your computer this change will be made active. If you're feeling impatient and don't want to wait for the server to automatically update you can do it manually:

```
sudo ntpdate-debian
```

I can't see a GUI option for this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I rebooted afterwards, but do you know how long it would take, until the clock is set according to the time server?

Comment: you can force it do update manually: using sudo ntpdate-debian; i've just updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Great, thanks, I will probably search for this after I install 11.10. Hopefully this will still work.